# Systemfilewatcher fires deleted event not correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a filewatcher:

```
private void initFileWatcherActive()
    {
        try
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = Global.Directory + Global.Machine + "\\" + Machines.Directories.Aktiv;

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
            NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
            NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
            NotifyFilters.FileName |
            NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
            NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.InternalBufferSize = 24000;


            watcher.Created -= new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChangedActive);
            watcher.Deleted -= new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChangedActive);

            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChangedActive);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChangedActive);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            setStatus("Filewatcher konnte nicht initialisiert werden: " + ex.Message, Level.ERROR);
        }
    }
```

With this call:

```
   private void OnChangedActive(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (e.ChangeType)
            {
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Created: break;

                case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:



                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => setStatus(ex.Message, Level.ERROR)));
        }

    }
```

If i add or delete files in windows explorer, everything works fine. 
But in my scenario, another .net programm adds the file with this code:

```
public static void add(String path, MachineOrder machineOrder, String fileExtention)
    {

        String filePath = path;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Auftragsnummer;" + machineOrder.Ordernumber);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Positionsnummer;" + machineOrder.Positionnumber);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Aenderungsdatum;" + machineOrder.Editdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Menge;" + machineOrder.Amount.ToString());
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Menge fertig;" + machineOrder.AmountReady.ToString());
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Termin;" + machineOrder.Deliverydate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Kundennummer;" + machineOrder.Customernumber);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Kundenname;" + machineOrder.Customername);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Kdauf.-nummer;" + machineOrder.CustomerOrdernumber);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Kdauf.-positionsnummer;" + machineOrder.CustomerOrdernumber);
        stringBuilder.AppendLine("Modell;" + machineOrder.Modell);


        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, string> characteristic in machineOrder.Charakteristics)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(characteristic.Key + ";" + characteristic.Value);
        }


        String filename = FilenameBuilder.buildFilename(machineOrder, fileExtention);

        filePath = filePath + "\\" + filename;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, stringBuilder.ToString());

    }
```

Now the filewatcher jumps into created, deleted, created, deleted and so on.. i have no clue why

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `FilenameBuilder.buildFilename()` do?  Is it possible that it creates and deletes files while trying to determine an unique file name?

Comment: The filenamebuilder only builds a name based on some parameters. it never creates or deletes anything in the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are instantiating multiple `FileSystemWatcher` instances, probably unintentionally.

`initFileWatcherActive` creates a new instance, removes event handlers, and adds new handlers.  The fact that you are trying to remove handlers from a brand new instance makes me think you call this function multiple times, probably intending to remove handlers from the existing instance. That would result in multiple watchers watching the same directory and make it look like the events happen more than once.

You should probably declare a single watcher, at a higher scope, and only instantiate it once.

Comment: i initiate it multiple times. but `Global.Machine` is always different